# What is a 2-norm of a multivariable complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I was wondering, is there a way to specify the $2$-norm of a multivariable complex function? For example if we have a complex function:
 $$f = f(x_1, x_2,\cdots, x_n) = Re\{f\} + j Im\{f\}, \ x_i \in \mathbb{R}$$ 
is there a method to obtain $\|f(x_1, x_2,\cdots, x_n) \|_2$ ? For the one-dimensional case $(f = f(x_1))$, it is known to be: $$\left( \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} |f|^2 dx_1 \right)^{1/2}$$

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Considering what you consider as the norm for one dimensional functions, the logic would be to define for $n$ dimensional functions:
$$\left(\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \cdots  \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \vert f\vert^2 dx_1 \cdots dx_n \right)^{1/2}$$

Comment: Is there a formal proof of this?

Comment: @Johny There cannot be a proof as it is more a definition.